# JQuery ajax JSON result to text input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, input

i have an Autocompleter, working fine, now i wanted to add an "Autofiller"
That means, if i select one of the "Companies" from the "Autocompleter" 
it should get all results from the DB for that Companies.

The JSON response is:

```
[
    {
        "idfirma": "2222",
        "firmenname": "test",
        "strasse": "test",
        "plz": "",
        "ort": "test",
        "l‌​and": "",
        "webseite": "",
        "region": "",
        "aktiv": "1"
    }
]
```

What i got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() {
        $( "#firma_neu" ).autocomplete({
            source: "./firma_suche.php3",
            open: function(event, ui) {
                    var firmenname = $("#firma_neu").val();
                    },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("#firma_neu").val(ui.item.label);
                    $("#idfirma_neu").val(ui.item.value);

                    // Hier muss der if selected aufruf kommen

                        var dataString = 'firmenID='+ ui.item.value ;
                          $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            data:  dataString,
                            url: "./loadFirma.php",
                            dataType: "json",

                             success: function(result){

                              $("#Strasse1").val(result.strasse);
                              $("#PLZ1").val(result.item.plz);
                              $("#Ort1").val(result.item.ort);
                              $("#Land1").val(result.item.land);
                              $("#Region1").val(result.item.region);

                             }
                           });

                    },
            minLength: 2
        });
    });

});
```

I get the correct answer from loadFirma.php but i cant use them...
result.strasse
and result.item.strasse
 
both wont work

Comment: you are not sending any data. Add `data: dataString` in your AJAX request.

Comment: ah sry added the data: dataString;

Comment: if i use: alert(result['strasse']) or alert(result.strasse)  both are empty. ----  alert(result) gives me out [object Object]

Comment: [{"idfirma":"2222","firmenname":"test","strasse":"test","plz":"","ort":"test","land":"","webseite":"","region":"","aktiv":"1"}]

Comment: you should avoid language mashup in code weil das schafft nur verwirrung

Comment: das hilft mir grad auch nicht weiter :P ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server side is outputting JSON but it is an array. See how it is surrounded by `[]`? So `result.strasse` does not exist.

Change to access the first element in the array before you try to access `strsse`:

```
$("#Strasse1").val(result[0].strasse);
```

If you expect multiple results then you can iterate over the array:

```
for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
    console.log(result[i].strasse)
}
```